# Sqoop - ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005 when trying to import from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hive, sqoop, parquet

I am trying to import a table from SQL server to Hive using Sqoop. Below is the command I am using:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://xxxxxxxxxx:1433;integratedSecurity=false;databaseName=xxxx;domain=xxxx" --username user -P --table notifications --split-by Id --hive-import --create-hive-table --hive-table testing.notifications --as-parquetfile --verbose
```

The hive table does not exist and the idea is to create it using my sqoop command. However, when I run my command, I get the following error:

```
18/09/05 08:40:21 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [notifications] AS t WHERE 1=0
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column Id of type [-5, 19, 0]
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column Dt of type [93, 23, 3]
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column path of type [12, 300, 0]
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column type of type [12, 1000, 0]
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column message of type [2005, 2147483647, 0]
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column person of type [12, 100, 0]
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column stage of type [12, 100, 0]
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column lastModified of type [93, 23, 3]
18/09/05 08:40:21 DEBUG util.ClassLoaderStack: Restoring classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@64c64813
18/09/05 08:40:21 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005
```

However, when I remove the `--as-parquetfile` argument from my command, it works fine. What's the issue with using `--as-parquetfile` ?

I would need the table to be in parquet and I tried using a `--query` argument to convert `Dt` and `lastModified` columns which are in `timestamp` (I guess timestamp is what `[93, 23, 3]` represents ) format to strings like this:

```
--query "select Id, convert(varchar(25),Dt,120) as Dt, path, type, message, person, stage, convert(varchar(25),lastModified,120) as lastModified from dbo.notifications"
```

and the logs confirm that the datatypes for `Dt` and `lastModified` have been modified:

```
18/09/05 09:30:12 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: select Id, convert(varchar(25),Dt,120) as Dt, path, type, message, person, stage, convert(varchar(25),lastModified,120) as lastModified from dbo.notifications WHERE  (1 = 0)
18/09/05 09:30:12 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column Id of type [-5, 19, 0]
18/09/05 09:30:12 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column Dt of type [12, 25, 0]
18/09/05 09:30:12 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column path of type [12, 300, 0]
18/09/05 09:30:12 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column type of type [12, 1000, 0]
18/09/05 09:30:12 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column message of type [2005, 2147483647, 0]
18/09/05 09:30:12 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column person of type [12, 100, 0]
18/09/05 09:30:12 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column stage of type [12, 100, 0]
18/09/05 09:30:12 DEBUG manager.SqlManager: Found column lastModified of type [12, 25, 0]
```

But it still fails with the same error.

I am not sure which column is causing the error. and I am also not sure if I can use `--map-column-hive` works with `--as-parquetfile`.

any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The error thrown is `Cannot convert SQL type 2005`, and you only have one column of type 2005: `Found column message of type [2005, 2147483647, 0]`. So there's your culprit. It's probably a `varchar(max)`, `nvarchar(max)`, or, heaven forbid, `text` type column that Sqoop needs help to interpret. I'm useless to you on the parquet issue, though.

Comment: I've arrived at the same conclusion myself after some debugging. I am now casting the `message` column to a `varchar(200)` and it is running fine! I see that the datatype for `message` in SQL server is `varchar` with `max_length = -1`. does this mean it is a `varchar(max)` ? Any idea what caused the error with this datatype? @EricBrandt

Comment: Be careful with that length of 200. [If a string value being converted/assigned to a varchar value exceeds the length specifier, the string is silently truncated.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-string). As to why, there are often issues with type conversions between engines. Hive doesn't have a data type that's _exactly_ like a varchar(max). String is close, but not close enough for implicit conversion to work. OTOH, it supports arrays, and SQL Server doesn't. Just one of those things to keep ETL fun for us.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the issue after some debugging. I realized that the error message: `ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Cannot convert SQL type 2005` has the datatype of the column that is causing the issue i.e. 2005 in my case which corresponds to `message` column in my source table. The `message` column is a `varchar` with `max_length = -1` which is a `varchar(max)`.

I cast it to a `varchar(200)` and that resolved my issue.

However, I am not sure why I had this issue only when using `--as-parquetfile` argument in my sqoop command. I'd love to hear more discussion on this issue.

Thank you.